# Cumbersome syntax for adding element to collection in F#

Tags: f#

```
type myClass(property1 : Map<int, string>) =
    member val Property1 = property1 with get, set

let myObject = myClass(Map.ofList [(1, "one"); (2, "two"); (3, "three")])
```

I understand correctly that for adding element to property collection we should write

```
myObject.Property1 <- myObject.Property1.Add (5, "five")
```

instead of

```
myObject.Property1.Add (5, "five")
```

? There is no more concise syntax? Thanks.

Comment: your problem is that you use a *immutable*  structure (`Map`) when you obviously want to mutate it - why don't you use `System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary` instead - you don't need a setter then eiter ... of course both is not *idiomatic* F# as you usually don't want the *mutation* in the first place

Comment: In this case `myDict.Add(5, "five")` would be more performance rather than `myMap <- myMap.Add (5, "five")`?

Comment: I don't think you would notice the difference in execution speed - only if you add lot's and lot's of elements - but what is the question here? Is it a syntax rant? A question about performance? A code-review?

Comment: I just wanted to know how do it better, but now I guess that choosing between immutable and mutable collections is separate and difficult topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# maps are immutable, so `Add` returns a new `Map` with the additional element. So if you're storing it in a class's property, yes you do have to assign the new `Map` to that property. There's no shortcut syntax because mutables aren't really idiomatic F#.

For this application you might find it preferable to open `System.Collections.Generic` and use `Dictionary`, which is mutable and probably more suitable for carrying around inside objects.